# How to import a file with correct method?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Actually I'm not in a real Ubuntu.I'm in *ubuntu on windows 10*.If I'm in a real ubuntu.I can use this command

```
ls >list.txt
```

to get a text file.And every line just contain one item(no redundant blank) 
[image]

But if I'm in windows disk

```
cd /mnt/d/VirtualNes/
ls >list.txt
```

Then I get a plain text file in *one line*

> [image]

So how to get a file whose every line contain one item without empty blank?

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting files in the two cases? my guess is that it's a matter of the interpretation of line endings

Comment: That looks like Notepad? Doubt Notepad can handle Linux line endings. If you use `nano` instead, it will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## When we had mechanical typewriters...

there were two things,

1. Carriage return, that moved the roller back when it reached the right margin and
2. Line feed, that moved the roller up so that the type heads won't
   write over the existing line, but write on a new line.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521685/why-does-windows-use-cr-lf

Here is a longer explanation of the history and some details on the CR and LF codes: http://penguinpetes.com/b2evo/index.php?title=argh_microsoft_notepad_crlf_argh

## Even today...

Windows uses CR/LF codes at the end of each line while Ubuntu (Linux in general) uses just the LF code.

When you open a text file generated by Ubuntu, real, virtual, or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), the file will look fine. When you open the same file in Windows, all the lines are together.

## What can you do?

First, verify that the text file created WSL actually have file names in separate lines:

```
cd /mnt/d/VirtualNes/
ls >list.txt
cat list.txt
```

The last line displays the contents of list.txt in the Ubuntu terminal. You should see the file looks fine.

Ubuntu comes with a terminal based text editor nano. You can use it to edit the text file instead of Notepad:

```
nano list.txt
```

On the other hand if you open the same file in Windows using notepad.exe, for example, you will see the lines jumbled up. You will get the same results if you create a similar file in "real" Ubuntu and open is in Windows.

If you want to open the text files created in Ubuntu in Windows you will have to convert the LF code at the end of each line to CR/LF code. You can do this in Windows CMD prompt (not the Ubuntu terminal) by entering:

```
TYPE list.txt | MORE /P > win_list.txt
```

You will get a new file `win_list.txt` that will open correctly in Windows.

There are other ways of doing this, such as `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` utilities. In Ubuntu you can install both these 2 utilities by the following command:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579553/windows-command-to-convert-unix-line-endings and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf for more.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of using ***notepad.exe***. Notepad is a very simple binary file editor, and it's based on ms-dos' notepad application. It requires CR/LF for new lines, instead of just LF, as linux and linux apps (and thus, Windows Subsystem for Linux/Bash on Ubuntu on Windows). So it will show everything on one line since it never sees CR/LF.

Other applications will read it correctly. Wordpad.exe will read the ls output as you expect. As will Word. Or IE. Or Chrome. Or any modern software designed in the last decade.

You can work around this for ***notepad.exe*** by piping it to a converter.

unix2dos is designed to do this. Or use other commands, like sed. Example:

`ls | sed -e 's/\r*$/\r/' > list.txt`

Will add the CR to the LF at the end, and notpad will show the file correctly.